# Jenkins with Hashicorp Vault SSH Keys

Tags: jenkins, ssh, vault, hashicorp

seeking to validate an approach and see what this means in terms of the tech and calls I need to use.
I would like Jenkins to pull an SSH key from Vault and use this to access a jump box A, then over the Internet to another jump box B and onto GIT, creating a new release.

I have worked out as far as I can to get the ssh keys into Vault.
How do I now from Jenkins, a) retrieve the key b) use the key to ssh to jumpbox A c) ssh over to jumpbox B and finally d) run a git command (imagine now that JBox B has some level of connection to it.

Many thanks!!

I am trying to analyse whether this is possible or not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.